# Wrong PS4 controller button mapping

Tags: bluetooth, games, steam, sdl

My PS4 controller mapping  strangely changed a week ago (ex : R2 trigger is now Start button). I tried to change the mapping manually with jstest it work for one game : Hollow Knight. But this method don't work for other games like Jotun or Sundered.

I also tried to purge and reinstall blueman. But it didn't change anything.
I also noticed that when not using the steam ps4 controller driver the back light isn't  flashy white but a weak blue.

Using the usb cable or not don't change anything in bluetooth mod.
Connecting with usb without bluetooth don't work.

Is there a way to get back to a "global" good maping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem to be the kernel to causing the problem. Using Grub Customizer I changed my kernel from 4.10.0-28 to 4.8.14-040814. Now the controller work correctly.